# Immer Komma bei impliziertem "dass"?

Tags: comma, punctuation

Es sei der folgende Satz:

> Ich weiß, dass das hier richtig geschrieben ist.

Nun kann ich diesen Satz umformulieren in:

> Ich weiß(,) das hier ist richtig geschrieben.

Sätze wie den zweiten schreibe ich immer mit einem Komma, aber manchmal kommt es vor, dass mir mein Sprachgefühl sagt, es wäre falsch. <= Hier übrigens wieder.

Soll man beim implizierten "dass", oder Worten, die einen ähnlichen Nutzen haben, immer ein Komma nutzen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Impliziertes dass* oder Worte, die einen *ähnlichen Nutzen* haben …

Das soll ja vermutlich heißen, dass beide Satzteile jeweils ein Subjekt und ein Prädikat haben. Dann gehört da auch ein Komma hin, um deutlich zu machen, wo der eine Teil aufhört und der andere anfängt.

> … dass mir mein **Sprachgefühl** **sagt**, *es wäre* falsch.

Es könnten ja sonst Missverständnisse aufkommen.

> … [mein Sprachgefühl sagt][es wäre falsch]

oder

> … [mein Sprachgefühl sagt es][wäre falsch]

Comment: Und ohne Komma ließe sich "Ich weiß(,) das hier ist richtig geschrieben." in [Ich weiß das hier][ist richtig geschrieben] teilen ... Danke für die Antwort; den Denkanstoß habe ich gebraucht.

Answer (score 2):

Im der Konstruktion

> [...] mein Sprachgefühl sagt, es wäre falsch. *`<= Hier übrigens wieder`*

liegt der Fall anders, weil hier *wäre* steht, und nicht *ist*. Das Komma trennt in diesem Fall die (metaphorische) indirekte Rede ab.

Ich vermute, dein gefühlsmäßiges Problem mit dem Satz

> Ich weiß, das hier ist richtig geschrieben.

geht auf seine latente Mehrdeutigkeit der zurück, denn der erste Teil (*ich weiß*) könnte sich auf einen anderen Sachverhalt beziehen, z.B. im folgenden Dialogfragment: *A: Du machst noch immer viele Grammatikfehler. B: Ich weiß, (aber) das hier ist richtig geschrieben.*

Die Konstruktion

> Ich weiß das hier ist richtig geschrieben.

ist grammatikalisch nicht korrekt (zwei gebeugte Verbformen, Hauptsatz und Nebensatz werden durch Komma getrennt). Allerdings wird sie von vielen Schreibern genutzt und von ihren Lesern offenbar selten missverstanden.

Einen Ausweg könnte der Doppelpunkt bieten,

> Ich weiß: das hier ist richtig geschrieben.

der mir persönlich schon oft aus der Klemme geholfen hat. Und mit dieser Einstellung scheine ich nicht isoliert zu stehen (siehe z.B. [44 Rezepte für attraktive Texte - Wolf Schneider verrät, wie man Texte verfasst, die dem Leser schmecken : literaturkritik.de](https://literaturkritik.de/id/9314):

> Die große Bedeutung, die Schneider den Satzzeichen beimisst, ist bemerkenswert: Mit Umsicht, ja mit Liebe müsse man sich ihrer bedienen, dann könne man mit "Satzzeichen Musik machen" [...]. Dass "erstrebenswerteste Satzzeichen" ist für Schneider hier nicht etwa der Punkt, sondern der Doppelpunkt.

Comment: Auch danke für diese ausführliche Erklärung! Ich denke meine leichte Unsicherheit kommt daher, dass ich aus Russland komme und deshalb eher immer davon ausgehe, ich würde es falsch schreiben, wenn ich es wo anders *anders* sehe. Da spielt auch eine Rolle, dass viele eher sparsam mit Kommas umgehen, was Du auch angesprochen hast, und ich mich dann anfange zu fragen, ob ich da nicht zu großzügig bin.

Comment: @akuzminykh Mit *großzügig* meinst du, dass du zu viele Kommas setzt? Ich beobachte in den letzten Jahren den Rückgang von Kommas in meinem Umfeld und führe das darauf zurück, dass viele Eigenheiten des Englischen ins Deutsche übernommen werden (teils auch völlig unreflektiert, beispielsweise das Auseinanderschreiben zusammengesetzter Substantive).

Comment: Richtig. Z. B. der Satz: *"Je mehr Aufgaben es gibt, desto mehr Aufwand muss betrieben werden, diese Aufgaben an Arbeiter zu verteilen."*: Wenn ich den Satz spreche, dann sitzen für mich die Kommas genau an den richtigen Stellen. Das ist aber so eine Gefühlssache bei mir, weil ich immer nach der "Taktung" eines Satzes gehe. Es bleibt aber auch immer eine Restunsicherheit, weil ich mir etwas nie über Grammatik- oder andere Regeln herleite.

Comment: @akuzminykh Interessant, wurdest du zweisprachig erzogen? Was ich bislang von dir gelesen habe macht auf mich einen sehr muttersprachlichen Eindruck.